# Image map - how display tooltip on hover and only when mouse stops

Tags: javascript, tooltip, imagemap

I'm a javascript beginner and I got stuck having a problem with displaying the tooltip (as a div) correctly for image map.

I want the tooltip appears only when the cursor is over an element (defined within the  tags) and only when the mouse stops on it.

I don't know why the added addEventListener method causes the tooltip to be displayed also after the onmouseout event is executed, i.e. when the cursor leaves a given  element.

https://jsfiddle.net/1b5mf06j/2/

```js
function myFuncHide(el) {

 var tooltip = document.getElementById('myTooltip');
 tooltip.style.display = 'none';

}

function myFunc (el) {
var tooltip = document.getElementById('myTooltip');
var timeout;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moving);

function moving() {

  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(mouseStop, 450);}
  
function mouseStop() {
var tooltip = document.getElementById('myTooltip');
tooltip.style.display = 'block';}
 
}
```

```css
#myTooltip {
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://tutorialspoint.com//images/usemap.gif" class="locations-map-full" alt="" usemap="#map">
<map name="map" id="locations-map">
 
<area shape="circle" coords="73,168,32" class="tooltip" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" onmouseout="myFuncHide(this)"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="74,0,113,29,98,72,52,72,38,27" class="tooltip" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" onmouseout="myFuncHide(this)"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="22,83,126,125" class="tooltip" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" onmouseout="myFuncHide(this)"/>
</map>
                    
               
<div id="myTooltip"> <p><img src="http://getbootstrap.com/apple-touch-icon.png" width="150px" height="150px" style="border: 1px solid #9b9999;"></p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mousemove` listener is on the `document` object and stays in effect regardless of where the mouse goes (in fact, additional listeners keeps getting piled on as you enter the area).

Here's a code rearrangement that adds cleanup to the `mouseout` event. It removes the listener and clears the timeout variable.

Also, I've done a little general code cleanup for you. Better function names. Removed some redundancy (remember DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself). Indentation. :)

```
var timeout;
var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('myTooltip');

function mouseMoving() {
  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
  
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
     tooltipEl.style.display = 'block';
  }, 450);
}

function ingress () {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoving);
}

function egress() {
  // cleanup
  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoving)
  
  tooltipEl.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can see the working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/alucheni/xmf5tjeh/25/.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected ;-) Great work and clarification. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no prob! if you don't mind, could you accept my answer? :)